# how to display the array list in question and answers with radio button format? using JSP and servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, arraylist, web-applications

I need to display the array list in question and ans format. I store entire questions and answers in the array list and I retrieved it in the `JSP` file but it is printing in web as a separate tables but not in the format. what should i correct in java file and as well as in `JSP` file
MY `JSP` part:

```
int i, k=0;
RegisterDao registerDao=new RegisterDao();
        ArrayList<String> list = registerDao.questionbank();
        System.out.println(list);
        for(i=0;i<list.size();i++){
}
```

my java part:

```
public ArrayList<String> questionbank(){
        ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();//creating new generic arraylist  

        try {



            Connection con =DbConnection.createConnection();
            String sql = "select * from questionbank";

            PreparedStatement  stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                //array.add(resultSet.getString("number"));
                        array.add(resultSet.getString("question"));
                        array.add(resultSet.getString("optionA"));
                        array.add(resultSet.getString("optionB"));
                        array.add(resultSet.getString("optionC"));
                        array.add(resultSet.getString("optionD"));
            }
                    //System.out.println(array);
                     return array;
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have every time 1 question and 4 Answers you could print the questions by accessing just every fifth element in the Array and using a second loop to access your answers inside 
`for(i=0;i<list.size();i+=5){
Print question 
  for(k=0;k<i + 5;k++){
    Print answer 
  }
}`